# Django Rest Framework Jwt + router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I want the front end to display token and refresk url.
Is there a way to add Jwt in the router?

I now use

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='my_jwt_token'),
     path('refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

I want to do something like this.

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'token', TokenObtainPairView)
router.register(r'token', TokenRefreshView)

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: You can inherite the serializer or use the serializer in your `ViewSet` at `retrieve()`. The serializer provides the data you need. However, at `retrieve()` you have to check and authenticate your user manually. Keep in mind `retrieve()` responses to a `get`-request. You can adjust it by changing values , e.g. `UserViewSet.as_view({'post': 'retrieve'})`. I recommend using the standard procedure. I predict you have to configure many things regard to the benefits of `ViewSet`s. What you could do is adding `extra actions for routing` but I guess manual authentication is still necessary.

Comment: @KlimBim I want to display the token api url on the frontend. I never thought it would be so troublesome.